# On which trilogy site does a "meta-computing" question belong?

Tags: discussion

I posted the question [Best Practices for managing virtual personae](https://superuser.com/questions/29177/best-practices-for-managing-virtual-personae) to SU some time ago and it received very little attention.  Maybe this is because it is not the appropriate place to ask the question.

The SU FAQ says:

> If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> … and it is not about videogames or
>   consoles, then you're in the right
>   place to ask your question!

My question was not hardware related and not particularly software related, so maybe SU was not the right place.

On the other hand I think that the issues I was trying to discuss would be of interest to people who appreciate the term "SuperUser" and the question does not seem to fit the profiles of StackOverflow ServerFault or Meta either.

Given [all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15456/can-we-please-have-more-strictness-on-su) [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5766/super-user-attracting-too-many-open-ended-subjective-questions) [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser) on what belongs on SU, does my question not have a place on the trilogy sites?

**EDIT**

I update the question title to reflect a more general question: ***Where do meta-computing questions belong?***

Comment: I wonder if it would be on-topic on https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/, and have asked a [meta question](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/are-questions-about-managing-virtual-personae-on-topic-here) over there (i.e. not all meta-computing questions in general, but questions about virtual personae).

Answer (score 4):

I think that SuperUser's criteria should be expanded to include meta computing topics, such as these. I certainly think your question is valid - and definately a question that I would expect to see on a site called "Super User".

Answer (score 1):

I am happy to see this on SU, however because of the subjective nature of meta questions and the fact that there won't be one concrete answer due to the discussion format of the question, they should be CW from the beginning.

Just a reminder, on the FAQ it also states:

> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

Meta question are generally very much in the above category and chances are they will be closely watched by the moderators.

Comment: What about if the question were community wiki?

Comment: @EvilChookie - Huh? Isn't that what I mentioned?